# Cannot delete or replace cookies with nodejs/

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have difficulties removing or replacing my cookies that I set with my login route. Whenever I login, the cookies are properly set, but when I click on logout, I can't seem to replace the cookies. I have tried `res.clearCookies` and it doesn't work either. I'm really not sure what's wrong.

This is my main app file

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

I have a login code snippet that looks like this,

```
export const login = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  db.getDB()
    .db()
    .collection("users")
    .findOne<User>({ email: email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email is not registered!" });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((correctPassword) => {
        if (correctPassword) {
          const userInfo = {
            userRef: user.userRef,
            role: user.role,
          };
          const accessToken = generateAccessToken(userInfo);
          const refreshToken = jwt.sign(userInfo, REFRESH_TOKEN, {
            expiresIn: "6h",
          });
          res.cookie("Refresh Token", refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "strict",
            path: "/",
          });
          res.cookie("Access Token", accessToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            sameSite: "strict",
            path: "/",
          });
          res.status(200).json({ message: "Cookies have been set!" });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ message: "Password is wrong!" });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};
```

and a logout snippet that looks like this

```
export const logout = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.cookie("Refresh Token", "x", {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
    path: "/",
    expires: new Date(1),
  });
  res.cookie("Access Token", "a", {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
    path: "/",
    expires: new Date(1),
  });
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Logged out succesfully." });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `res.clearCookies()`, I found that `res.clearCookie('Access Token')` works to clear a cookie.

Comment: I tried 
res.clearCookie("Refresh Token");
res.clearCookie("Access Token");
and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

do you add `{withCredentials: true}` to your request from the frontend ?

My logout function on frontend(next.js) using axios:

```
logout: (state) => {
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

                axios.get('http://localhost:9090/logout', {withCredentials: true})
                    .then(() => {
                        localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'false');
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Error during logout:', error);
                    });
            }
        },
```

in `fetch` library:

```
fetch("https://example.com", {
  credentials: "include",
});
```

Backend endpoint (express):

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie("access_token", { httpOnly: true, path: "/", maxAge: -1 })
  res.clearCookie("refresh_token", { httpOnly: true, path: "/", maxAge: -1 })
  res.clearCookie("expires_in", { httpOnly: true, path: "/", maxAge: -1 })
  return res.json({ status: "Logged out" })
})
```

All cookies have been cleared